# Apple mach-o Linker (id)Error in Xcode when trying to build the app on the iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am desperately searching for a solution. I am currently trying to make a test app with Unity AR Foundation for an apple device (iphone 8 software 13.4 and my macbook - sierra) since i don't want to upgrade anything i downloaded the Xcode 9.2 and the building process in Xcode ends up showing tones of warnings and this:

[image]

please, help, i have searched the internet for an answer but nothing works for me. Maybe also because I am new to all this. Would appreciate any help!

P.S.:if it helps, i've been following this tutorial -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu_eG0eTFlA&list=PL6VJLOFcTt7awvyIGIbLLPOBrW6-Y1R-J&index=3&t=0s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, it seems like you're missing: `ARKit.framework`

To include a framework in your Xcode project:

1. In the project navigator, select your project.
2. Select your target.
3. Open "*Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Content*" expander.
4. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button.
5. Select your framework.

Comment: no, it was all there. What was missing was the apple update :-( 
after I updated my system and had the newest Xcode version everything went perfect. So, let's just try not to make the system angry and keep updating our MacBooks......or just don't buy MacBooks....